# How to solve permission denied error on Huawei Cloud DB

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

I implemented the Huawei's Cloud DB and Auth Service into my project. After i create my Cloud DB Zone and Object Types i tried to use the executeUpsert() function of Cloud DB. But i got an error message that says "Permission Denied". Program executes all database operations after user authenticated. And authenticated users has permission to update the table. I don't know how to solve this permission problem. Does anyone have opinion?

Error Message;
[image]

Comment: hi@Tolgahan Tutar, Can you check whether the Auth Service is successfully logged in?

Comment: I checked it, i can get the logged user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to some employees who are authorized in Huawei's Cloud DB and they helped me to find the cause of the problem. When i was getting the error, as you see in the screenshot below, **the instance when user gets authentication** and **the instance when i initialize the AGConnectCloudDB** were **different.**

[image]

after i defined the instance object globally and **use the same instance when i am getting the auth and also initializing the AGConnectCloudDB object** as you see in the below picture, the problem is solved!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though you implemented Huawei's Cloud DB and Auth Service into your project, there are still cases that can cause the “permission denied” error. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-error-code-0000001117436042

Please check the following areas in your project to rule out the causes.

[image]

If in the log, you see auth error as well, please check:
[image]

If the above are all cleared out and the issue is still there, please provide more details for further troubleshooting.

Comment: I changed the initialization of the AGConnectCloudDB object from `val instance = AGConnectInstance.buildInstance(AGConnectOptionsBuilder().setRoutePolicy(
                AGCRoutePolicy.CHINA).build(this)); mCloudDB = AGConnectCloudDB.getInstance(instance, AGConnectAuth.getInstance(instance))` to `mCloudDB = AGConnectCloudDB.getInstance()` and problem solved. I know the new method is deprecated but i couldn't find any other way and i don't get why it is solved the problem.